# Xcodeのシュミレーターが横向きにならない

Tags: xcode

本の情報によるとアプリの設定画面の「Deployment info」で「 Landscape Left」だけにチェックするとシュミレーターが横画面になると書いてあり下の図の様にしたのですがシュミレーターは縦画面のままです。

どの様な原因が考えられますか？

ちなみに画像を載せようとしましたが2imb以下にしてくれという表示で断念しております

Deployment info

Deployment Target     10.3

Devices                      iPhone

Maine interface         Main

Device Orientation  Portrait

```
                            Upside Down
```

チェック済み   →   Landscape Left

```
                            Landscape Right
```

Status Bar Style      Light

Comment: 画面キャプチャーについては、jpegかpngに変換してやれば、2MBを超えることは稀だと思います。(Mac OS 標準付属のPreviewなんかでも簡単に変換できます。)私の回答が、あなたの直面している問題とは違うという場合、「編集」してご質問に画像を含めていただければ、より分かりやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: とても分かりやすい説明ありがとうございました

Comment: XCODEのバージョンの違いによるkyodouの変化で解決しました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***どの様な原因が考えられますか？***

単にXcodeのバージョンによる挙動の違いでしょう。どのバージョンからだったのか記録は残していませんが、現在のXcodeでは、アプリをLandscapeオンリーに設定しても、シミュレータの表示の向きには影響しなくなってしまっています。

アプリをLandscapeオンリーに設定すると言うことは、ユーザがデバイスを縦に持った時にも、アプリは画面を横長方向に使うと言うことなので、現在のXcodeのシミュレータは、デフォルトでは「ユーザがデバイスを縦に持った時」の動作をシミュレートしていると言うことになります。

ボタン1個の画像で恐縮ですが、こんな感じなら正解ということです。
[image: Landscape縦持ち画像]

ユーザがデバイスを横持ちした時の状態にするには、Simulatorのメニューから

#### Hardware > Rotate Left

#### Hardware > Rotate Right

を選んで、明示的に回転させてください。